# Does MT support SMTP?

Tags: smtp, xamarin.ios

Does MT support SMTP SendMail, or am I stuck with MFMailComposeViewController?  Right now, I have it working (MFMailComposeViewController), but when I add an attachment, the mail is not received by the receipient.

I was wondering if SMTP would be more reliable and handle attachments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is supported its under System.Net.Mail but it is not recommended to be used because there is no way to get the user credentials from the system unless you ask for them on your application but i dont know if its against the EULA of apple.

i have successfully sent email with attachments from the iphone using the following code hope this helps :)

```
MFMailComposeViewController _mail;
mailButton.TouchUpInside += (o, e) =>
            {
                byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("photo.png");
                NSData datas = NSData.FromArray(data);
                if (MFMailComposeViewController.CanSendMail) 
                {
                    _mail = new MFMailComposeViewController ();
                    _mail.SetMessageBody ("This is the body of the email", false);
                    _mail.AddAttachmentData(datas, "image/png", "photo.png");
                    _mail.Finished += delegate(object sender, MFComposeResultEventArgs e1) 
                    {
                        if (e1.Result == MFMailComposeResult.Sent) 
                        {
                            UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView ("Mail Alert", "Mail Sent", null, "Success", null);
                            alert.Show ();

                            //you should handle other values that could be returned in e.Result and also in e.Error 
                        }
                            e1.Controller.DismissModalViewControllerAnimated (true);
                    };

                    this.PresentModalViewController (_mail, true);

                } else {
                    //handle not being able to send mail
                }
            };
```

Also here is the link to the test solution, its based on mike bluestein's example http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2058130/MailDemo.zip and it works for me :)

hope this helps

Alex

Comment: Hi Alex... still not working... I have a Q: why do you have "this.PresentModalViewController" twice? (in _mail.Finished and in the main code?  Is the second one necessary? (maybe that's my problem?)

Comment: Ignore the previous post... I have a ticket open in my email provider to see if they are blocking it... I just might have to go to SMTP because I then have control of the credentials.  More tomorrow.

Comment: oh ok, you could try with a gmail account for example (Wich i did set up on my iPhone to try the example) to see if it is your email provider :), if there is anything else i can help drop me a line. Alex

Comment: That was my next thing to do... will get back to you, and thank you for the time you are spending on this.  Oh, one more thing... let me post the latest code and maybe you can see something... post is here:  http://monobin.com/__d59516457

Comment: I got it working (not sure how)... can now send with attachment to all addresses with the exception of any GMail address, unless it's coming from GMail.  I suspect they are blocking it.  Thanks for taking the time to look into it.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Whether it supports it or not, you shouldn't use it.

You have no way of getting the user's SMTP connection settings, so you cannot send mail as the user.

You cannot assume that the user's connection can connect to your server.